# MultiDatePicker onChange not called if selection is set programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I try to select a date (today) in a MultiDatePicker programmatically via a Button. The selection works as expected and the onChange modifier will be called and the day today is marked as selected in the Picker. But when I try to deselect the date directly in the MultiDatePicker, the date is not marked anymore but the onChange modifier will not get called. If you tap on another date in the MultiDatePicker now, both dates, the other date and the date today are marked as selected.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.calendar) private var calendar

    @State private var selectedDates: Set<DateComponents> = []

    @State private var onChangeCounter = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MultiDatePicker("Select dates", selection: $selectedDates)
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                .onChange(of: selectedDates) { _ in
                    self.onChangeCounter += 1
                }

            Button("Select today") {
                let todayDatecomponents = calendar.dateComponents(in: calendar.timeZone, from: Date.now)
                selectedDates.insert(todayDatecomponents)
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(minWidth: 150)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.accentColor)
            .cornerRadius(20)

            HStack {
                Text("onChangeCounter")
                Spacer()
                Text(String(onChangeCounter))
            }
            .padding()

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: iPhone Screenvideo]

Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible to select a date in the MultiDatePicker programmatically?

Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For purposes of this discussion, **Today** means ***December 17, 2022***

The issue is that `Date.now` is not equal to **Today**

I'm in US East Coast Time Zone... if I add a button to `print(Date.now)` and tap it, I see this in the debug console:

```
2022-12-17 14:08:52 +0000
```

if I tap it again 4-seconds later, I see this:

```
2022-12-17 14:08:56 +0000
```

Those two dates are ***not*** equal.

So, let's find out what the `MultiDatePicker` is using for it's `selection`.

Change your `MultiDatePicker` to this:

```
        MultiDatePicker("Select dates", selection: $selectedDates)
            .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
            .onChange(of: selectedDates) { _ in
                print("onChange")
                selectedDates.forEach { d in
                    print(d)
                }
                print()
                self.onChangeCounter += 1
            }
```

If I run the app and select Dec 14, 19 and 8, I see this:

```
onChange
calendar: gregorian (current) era: 1 year: 2022 month: 12 day: 14 isLeapMonth: false 

onChange
calendar: gregorian (current) era: 1 year: 2022 month: 12 day: 14 isLeapMonth: false 
calendar: gregorian (current) era: 1 year: 2022 month: 12 day: 19 isLeapMonth: false 

onChange
calendar: gregorian (current) era: 1 year: 2022 month: 12 day: 14 isLeapMonth: false 
calendar: gregorian (current) era: 1 year: 2022 month: 12 day: 19 isLeapMonth: false 
calendar: gregorian (current) era: 1 year: 2022 month: 12 day: 8 isLeapMonth: false
```

Now, I de-select the 19th, and I see this:

```
onChange
calendar: gregorian (current) era: 1 year: 2022 month: 12 day: 14 isLeapMonth: false 
calendar: gregorian (current) era: 1 year: 2022 month: 12 day: 8 isLeapMonth: false
```

The 19th was correctly removed from the `Set`.

Now, I tap your "Select today" button, and I see this:

```
onChange
calendar: gregorian (current) era: 1 year: 2022 month: 12 day: 14 isLeapMonth: false 
calendar: gregorian (current) era: 1 year: 2022 month: 12 day: 8 isLeapMonth: false 
calendar: gregorian (current) timeZone: America/New_York (fixed (equal to current)) era: 1 year: 2022 month: 12 day: 17 hour: 9 minute: 24 second: 11 nanosecond: 339460015 weekday: 7 weekdayOrdinal: 3 quarter: 0 weekOfMonth: 3 weekOfYear: 51 yearForWeekOfYear: 2022 isLeapMonth: false
```

As we can see, these two lines:

```
let todayDatecomponents = calendar.dateComponents(in: calendar.timeZone, from: Date.now)
selectedDates.insert(todayDatecomponents)
```

Insert a `DateComponents` object with a **lot** more detail.

If I tap "Select today" again, I get this:

```
onChange
calendar: gregorian (current) era: 1 year: 2022 month: 12 day: 8 isLeapMonth: false 
calendar: gregorian (current) era: 1 year: 2022 month: 12 day: 14 isLeapMonth: false 
calendar: gregorian (current) timeZone: America/New_York (fixed (equal to current)) era: 1 year: 2022 month: 12 day: 17 hour: 9 minute: 24 second: 11 nanosecond: 339460015 weekday: 7 weekdayOrdinal: 3 quarter: 0 weekOfMonth: 3 weekOfYear: 51 yearForWeekOfYear: 2022 isLeapMonth: false 
calendar: gregorian (current) timeZone: America/New_York (fixed (equal to current)) era: 1 year: 2022 month: 12 day: 17 hour: 9 minute: 26 second: 39 nanosecond: 866878032 weekday: 7 weekdayOrdinal: 3 quarter: 0 weekOfMonth: 3 weekOfYear: 51 yearForWeekOfYear: 2022 isLeapMonth: false
```

Now `selectedDates` contains two "today dates" ... 2-minutes and 28-seconds apart.

When I tap the 17th on the calendar, there is no matching date in that `set` to remove... so when the calendar refreshes (such as when I select another date), the 17th still shows as selected.

So, let's change the programmatically inserted `DateComponents` to match the calendar's data:

```
let todayDatecomponents = calendar.dateComponents([.calendar, .era, .year, .month, .day], from: Date.now)
selectedDates.insert(todayDatecomponents)
```

Now when we tap `17` on the calendar it will be de-selected ***and*** the matching object `selectedDates` will be removed.

Here's how I modified your code to debug:

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct MultiDateView: View {
    @Environment(\.calendar) private var calendar
    
    @State private var selectedDates: Set<DateComponents> = []
    
    @State private var onChangeCounter = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MultiDatePicker("Select dates", selection: $selectedDates)
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                .onChange(of: selectedDates) { _ in
                    print("onChange")
                    selectedDates.forEach { d in
                        print(d)
                    }
                    print()
                    self.onChangeCounter += 1
                }
            
            Button("Select today") {
                let todayDatecomponents = calendar.dateComponents(in: calendar.timeZone, from: Date.now)
                selectedDates.insert(todayDatecomponents)
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(minWidth: 150)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.accentColor)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            
            Button("Select today the right way") {
                let todayDatecomponents = calendar.dateComponents([.calendar, .era, .year, .month, .day], from: Date.now)
                selectedDates.insert(todayDatecomponents)
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(minWidth: 150)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            
            HStack {
                Text("onChangeCounter")
                Spacer()
                Text(String(onChangeCounter))
            }
            .padding()
            
            Button("Print Date.now in debug console") {
                print("debug")
                print("debug:", Date.now)
                print()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(minWidth: 150)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.red)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct MultiDateView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MultiDateView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You sir are a wizard. what solid debugging

Answer (score 2):

it looks like `MultiDatePicker` is saving additional components.

Use this to set the today components:

```
let todayDatecomponents = calendar.dateComponents([.calendar, .era, .year, .month, .day], from: .now)
```